# Call into Lua from TI-BASIC

Tags: lua, ti-basic, ti-nspire

I have an nspire calculator and after writing a hash table implementation, found the BASIC environment to be a pretty offensive programming environment. Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware, it's impossible to use Lua to write libraries.

I did see that somewhere in the Lua interface you can detect variable changes so it might be possible within a file to use Lua functions, but I fear it will go out of scope if used externally.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's not impossible to write Lua libraries for a TI-Nspire. You can put the libraries code into a string, store it as a variable in TI-Basic and put the file in the MyLibs folder. Then, when you want to load your library, do `loadstring(var.recall("libfilename/programstring"))()`. This will load the library's code as a string from that files, compile it (using loadstring), and execute it (practicaly the same as `require`).

Also, about getting from controlling a Lua script using TI-Basic, depending on what you want to do, you could use `math.eval("<some TI-Basic code>")`. This will execute the code in TI-Basic, and return the result as a Lua value (or string). This way, you can call a TI-Basic function every once in a while, and act according to its output.